# Using sourceCpp and RcppArmadillo

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm trying to create build a package with a few functions using Rcpp and RcppArmadillo (Rstudio in Windows). However, I ran into some issues, and I'd appreciate your input. The following is the .cpp file (called update_s.cpp):

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

using namespace arma;
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

NumericVector update_sigma(NumericMatrix Theta, NumericMatrix Y, NumericMatrix M, NumericVector lambda, int nu){
  int n = Y.ncol();
  int K = Y.nrow();
  int R = Theta.ncol();
  double N = n;
  NumericVector Den(n);
  NumericMatrix Thetasq(n, R);
  NumericMatrix Residual(K, n);
  NumericMatrix Res_sq(K, n);
  NumericMatrix Tmp(n, K);
  NumericVector scale;
  NumericVector sigma(K);

  for (int j = 0; j < R; j++){
    arma::Thetasq.col(j) = pow( arma::Theta.col(j), 2);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    Den(i) = sum(Thetasq.row(i));
  }
  Residual = Y - M* arma::trans(Theta);
   for(int i = 0; i < K; i++){
   Res_sq.row(i) = pow(Residual.row(i),2); 
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < K; j++){
      Tmp(i,j) = Res_sq(j,i)/Den(i);
    }  
  }
  scale = (nu*lambda)/(N + nu) + (1/(N + nu))*(sum(Tmp));
  for (int k = 0; k < K; k++){
  sigma(k) = ((N + nu)*scale(k))/(R::rchisq(N + nu));
  }

  return sigma;
}
```

When I run this from R:

```
sourceCpp('Docs/Bayes/update_s.cpp')
```

This is the error I get:

```
update_s.cpp:26:5: error: 'Thetasq' is not a member of 'arma'
update_s.cpp:26:33: error: 'Theta' is not a member of 'arma'
update_s.cpp:31:38: error: no matching function for call to 'trans(Rcpp::NumericMatrix&)'
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting the error. From looking at online tutorials it seems that the way to use RcppArmadillo functions into Rcpp is by using:

```
arma::function();
```

Is that correct? Or is there another way to use them. Please let me know.

Thanks,

Napo

Comment: Armadillo functions expect Armadillo data types and not Rcpp data types.

Comment: What Roland said. See the copious examples at eg the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org).

Comment: Thanks for the information Roland and Dirk. I made those changes and it's working fast and nice!